# Copy column 1 value into column 2 in Sharepoint List ( copy col1 value into col2 in the same list when adding a new item)

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to copy value of col 1 into col 2 when adding a new item to the form and make sure it is editable

Comment: Is SharePoint classic view or modern view? what's the Intention( as seems duplicate values)?

Comment: Its a classic view, when a user selects a value from a choice column it should populate in the text area field and should be editable for the user.

Comment: @Lee_MSFT can you please help me regarding calling a java rest api and populating the fields automatically in the columns of sharepoint list?

Comment: @Lee_MSFT how do I do it for singleline field? $('textarea[Title="MultipleLineField"]').val(ChangeValue); is it the same instead of MultipleLineField I put the SingleLine field value? like $('textarea[Title="SingleLineField"]').val(ChangeValue);

Comment: Single line text filed render as HTML input control, so try $('input[Title="SingleLineField"]')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Script for your reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var optionControl=$('select[Title="UserChoice"]');
            var defaultValue = $('select[Title="UserChoice"] option:selected').text();
            console.log(defaultValue);
            $('textarea[Title="MultipleLineField"]').val(defaultValue);
            optionControl.change(function () {
                var ChangeValue = $('select[Title="UserChoice"] option:selected').text();
                console.log(ChangeValue);
                $('textarea[Title="MultipleLineField"]').val(ChangeValue);
            })
        })
    </script>
```

Field setting
[image]

Sample result
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey can we use a java web service to auto populate some fields based on the selection of drop down column in the same code?

Comment: There is a rest service I need to use to populate some fields when the drop down is selected.

Comment: I think you can call any external service, while it relates to your service authentication/Authorization. I have little experience about java. So you may post with proper tag if you need help.

Comment: As you mentioned in your code regarding the copying column into another, I am using ajax to call the service .

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/247363/populate-specific-items-of-the-sharepoint-online-list-using-java-webservice-when

Comment: Please find the question I posted ..https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/247433/ajax-call-to-rest-service-not-workingno-response