# Populate Specific items of the SharePoint Online List using Java webservice when a Drop-down column is selected while creating a new item

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery-ajax

I need to populate certain columns of the list when I select a value from the dropdown column in the same list. Say for example I select create Item in the list and then I have a column called FlightNumber, when I select a particular flight number, I need to use Java webservice to call and populate certain fields in the list based on the FlightNumber I selected. I did try searching but was unable to figure out, please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1  :You can attach a JSLink to your fields and in that javascript you can write js code to call your Java webservice and auto populate other field value.

below are few code samples available using JSLink

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a

Option 2 :SPFx extension field Customizer

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer

With JSLink i have done a similar code where we need to query User profile service when user enter the username and populate other data in columns. so it was achievable.

Comment: I have a rest api which I need to call and get only certain objects from the json and populate in the list fields, can I get any code sample so that I can follow the same?

Comment: Prashanth, Please have a look to below link how JS link works, So first you need to attach a Javascript with JSlink property, you need to override Field "FlightNumber" in Edit and Add mode, in this override you can call a javascript method there you can call your json and do all other javascript activity. even you can attach onchange event in that script so every time Filight Number change you call your Service. https://www.aerieconsulting.com/blog/using-a-js-link-override-in-sharepoint-online