# Ajax call to Rest service not working(no response)

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery-ajax

I am trying to call a rest service using ajax in SharePoint online list form by adding a web part. Here is the code attached. SharePoint is https where as my java rest service is http. I am confused how to get a response. When I debugged it says content media blocked!. Please help me with this.

```
 $.ajax({
                url:"http://54.227.190.149:8080/crew-dashboard-rest-services-0.0.1/aircraftView",
                type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: false , dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
                success: function (result) {
                   alert("success");
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                   alert("error");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call **`unsecured`** web service in a **`secured`** website that called a **`Mix Content`**.

**Unfortunately,** this doesn't work!! you will need to call a **`secure HTTPS`** web service to get it working as expected!

**As a temporary workaround**, try to [enable Mixed Content in your browser](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/04/03/only-secure-content-is-displayed-allow-display-mixed-content/) that may work!

Comment: but the SharePoint list will be used by various people, they cannot every time go and change it right? The values should be populated automatically.  I have a http api which needs to integrated into sharepoint list which is https.

Comment: Totaly Agree with you, it's unpractical solution so I said it's temporary! and as a permanent solution based on my humble experience,  you must use a secure HTTPS web service URL to get it work!

Comment: Hi Mohamed I have posted a new question regarding https. Please find the link for the qyestion - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/247918/unresolvablehostname-sharepoint-online-the-provided-host-name-abc-com-could-n

Comment: Sure, I will and I do hope to can help you :)